# .net 6 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt different behaviour between 6.24.0 and 6.34.0

Tags: .net, minimal-apis

Due to vulnerability warning in most 6.x versions of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, I upgraded to the first non-vulnerable release 6.34.0. Problem is, I receive *bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="the signature key was not found"* as a result of the same jwt being processed. I was searching for a clear difference between these two releases, but found no clue at the moment.

I was unable to solve the issue with any non-vulnerable release.
Is it possible that a configuration default has changed or the entire jwt processing is incompatible between 6.24.0 and 6.34.0?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  local development in your IDE?  or after a deployed CD/CI pipeline build?

Comment: Hi!. Both local development and deployed as a Windows service. It makes no difference.